# How do I move calendar events together to keep a constant time in between?

Tags: macos, ios, calendar, ical

some procedures I do regularly require that I do something, say, on day 1, 3, 14, and 40, and I usually make Calendar / iCal events for planning. Is it possible to create a group of events such that if I shift the start date of the first event, all the other events are postponed accordingly? These changes should eventually appear on my apple calendar, but I could also use other software that can sync to Apple Calendar, provided that it is not too complex.

Ideal would be if I could also copy the whole group of events and paste it to a different date to repeat the whole procedure.

I have experimented with some apps. 
Aeon timeline could be manageable but doesn't have Calendar sync. 
Pagico might be able to do this but I found it rather complex to use.

I just wonder if there is a simple solution to handle such project planning tasks. I figured I don't need a full-blown project management app for this. I have a mac (Sierra, Mojave) and an iphone.